# Why do some of my powertop commands not work

Tags: 13.10, power-management, powertop

I'm trying to make my powertop tweaks permanent.  I ran sudo powertop --html and the I have a list of the commands I need to add to /etc/rc.local.  I added them to /etc/rc.local and most of them work, but some of them don't.  For example, the command to set VM writeback timeout to from bad to good is...

```
echo '1500' > '/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs';
```

This command does not work even though I added it to the /etc/rc.local file.  A few other commands related to enableing SATA link power managmenet also don't work such as...

```
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy';
```

These are also in the /etc/rc.local file.  Here is a copy of my rc.local file

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# these commands work
echo '0' > '/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control';

# these commands don't work
echo '1500' > '/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy';
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy';
echo '1' > '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control';

exit 0
```

Why don't these commands work?

UPDATE:

When I run this script through a command prompt the commands work fine.  So if I start my system, log in, and open a command prompt and type...

sudo /etc/rc.local

The script runs fine and all settings in powertop are properly set. So this means that the script is executable and that the command syntax is okay.

I'm betting that rc.local script is executed properly during startup, but that something else after this is resetting the powertop settings that aren't working.  Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: I have a similar issue with Ubuntu server 12.04LTS. Have you tried to ask about this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167820/startup-commands-in-etc-rc-local-wont-work

The first comment recommends to "Add set -x; exec >/var/log/rc.local.log 2>&1 at the top of /etc/rc.local just below the #!/bin/sh".

That helped me to find the problem of the programs I was attempting to run.